# Date in phonegap doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, android, date, cordova, calendar

When I save a meeting in my application and in calendar of the mobile. In my application, I got the date normally. But in the calendar(mobile Native) I found dateStart 10h00, dateEnd 10h00, I should have dateStart 09h00, dateEnd 10h00 .

I used this code to save the meeting in the calendar from this github [Calendar Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/cc57eeec417f7a41d8ffcb07a0986192df4fb712/README.md).

```
      var startDate = new Date(2014,4,18,9,0,0,0,1);
//The time in console : Fri Apr 18 2014 9:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
      var endDate = new Date(2014,4,18,10,0,0,0,1);
      var title = "My nice event";
      var location = "Home";
      var notes = "Some notes about this event.";
      var success = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
      var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };

   var calOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions(); // grab the defaults
  calOptions .firstReminderMinutes = 60; // default is 60, pass in null for no reminder (alarm)
  window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,calOptions,success,error);
```

Comment: ALthough I am not well versed with phone gap, this might have something to do with locale?

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you posted I can see you have no `options` variable and you used it in:

```
window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,options,success,error);
```

Try this updated snippet:

```
     var startDate = new Date(2014,4,18,9,0,0,0,1);
//The time in console : Fri Apr 18 2014 9:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
      var endDate = new Date(2014,4,18,10,0,0,0,1);
      var title = "My nice event";
      var location = "Home";
      var notes = "Some notes about this event.";
      var success = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
      var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };

    var calOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions(); // grab the defaults
      calOptions.firstReminderMinutes = 120; // default is 60, pass in null for no reminder (alarm)
      window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,calOptions,success,error);
```